# passing the context to another method

Tags: iphone, ios, core-graphics

What is the correct way of passing the drawing context to another method in the same class from `drawRect()` ?

do you just pass it like this?

```
drawMoreStuff:(CGContextRef)context
```

or do you use the functions:
`UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();` and `CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);` at the beginning and end of the function respectively ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, a context that is passed to a function may not always be the same as the current context, so the best way would be like in your first example.

```
- (void)drawMoreStuff:(CGContextRef)context {
```

Depending on your function though, you would use the current context if you have a function like:

```
- (void)drawMoreStuffToCurrentContext {
```